# How do I adb disconnect an emulator and keep it disconnected?

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I have somehow gotten a couple of Android emulators connected via ADB and I can't get rid of them.

```
> adb devices -l
List of devices attached
emulator-5554          device product:sdk_gphone_x86 model:sdk_gphone_x86 device:generic_x86_arm transport_id:1
emulator-5556          device product:sdk_gphone_x86 model:sdk_gphone_x86 device:generic_x86_arm transport_id:2
```

When I `adb disconnect` it disconnects everything, but they come back almost instantly (with an incremented `transport_id`)

When I `adb kill-server` and then `adb devices -l` it restarts the adb server (as expected) and reconnects the emulators.  I understand that it scans the even ports from 5554 : https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#howadbworks

When I run the emulator list devices they don't appear:

```
> .\emulator.exe -list-avds
Nexus_5_API_30
Pixel_2_API_29_x86_64
Pixel_4a_API_30
Tablet_API_30
```

I don't think I've got another Android SDK Emulator suite installed locally.

Comment: Only running emulators should appear as devices.  Kill the process they're running on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of killing an emulator would be:

```
adb -s emulator-5554 emu kill
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the process that was running the emulators:
On windows, using Powershell:

```
> Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 5554).OwningProcess

 NPM(K)    PM(M)      WS(M)     CPU(s)      Id  SI ProcessName
 ------    -----      -----     ------      --  -- -----------
    134 4,074.23   1,998.07   2,544.47   12528   1 qemu-system-x86_64-headless
```

And killing that using the process manager did the trick.